# i get this error: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string in laravel ORM

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I get this error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

when I run this code:

```
 public function index()
{
    save_resource_url();
    //$items = News::with(['category', 'photos'])->get(); 

    $items = Solicitud::rightjoin(News::with(['category', 'photos']),'news.id','=','solicitud.event_id')->count('*','event_id','as','total')->get();
    return $this->view('news_events.index', compact('items'));
}
```

my original sql query

> SELECT *,count(event_id) as total FROM solicitud  RIGHT JOIN news ON news.id = solicitud.event_id group by title;

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you are putting the `Builder` as first parameter `News::with(['category', 'photos'])`. it should only be the string(table name) like `'news'`.

[Click here to read more](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_rightJoin)

So the query should

```
$items = Solicitud::rightjoin( 'news','news.id','=','solicitud.event_id')->count('*','event_id','as','total')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve:

my original code

```
 public function index()
{
    save_resource_url();
    $items = News::with(['category', 'photos'])->get();         
    return $this->view('news_events.index', compact('items'));
}
```

change my sql query:

> SELECT *,count(event_id) as total FROM solicitud RIGHT JOIN news ON news.id = solicitud.event_id group by title;

this query produced duplicate columns

for this:

> select news.*,count(event_id) as total from news left join solicitud on solicitud.event_id = news.id group by news.id;

this query shows only the columns of the users table plus the 'total' table in relation to the 'request' table

in my code transform to eloquent

```
 public function index()
{
    save_resource_url();
    $items = News::with(['category', 'photos'])->leftjoin('solicitud','solicitud.event_id','=','news.id')->groupBy('news.id')->select('news.*',DB::raw('count(event_id) as total'))->get();
    return $this->view('news_events.index', compact('items'));
}
```